# Wordpress user permalink change issue

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

I'm trying to change the link of the user profile and it seems that I'm too noob.
The current structure of the link is: **domain.com/profile/username**.
What I want is to be is like: **domain.com/username/city** where *city* is taken from wp_postmeta table

I tried something using this function:

```
add_action('init', 'wpse82004_init');

function wpse82004_init()

{

    global $wp_rewrite;

    $city = get_user_meta( get_current_user_id(), 'city', TRUE ); 

    $wp_rewrite->author_base = $city;

    $wp_rewrite->author_structure = '/%author%' . '/' . $wp_rewrite->author_base;

}
```

The problem is that is returns the city of the current logged user on all profiles I click.
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: you don't want to call `get_current_user_id()`, instead you should parse the `username` in the url and get its `city` value to rewrite

Comment: It is possible to do that? Can you help me please?

Comment: It is possible to do that using a foreach loop where you get all the IDs?

Answer (score 1):

**untested code**

```
add_action('init', 'wpse82004_init');

function wpse82004_init()

{

    global $wp_rewrite;

    //parse username from url
    $url = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
    $username = preg_replace('/^.*profile\/(.*)$/i', '$1', $url);

    //get user by username
    $user = get_user_by('slug', $username);

    //rewrite the city value of anticipated user other than current user
    $city = get_user_meta( $user->ID, 'city', TRUE ); 

    $wp_rewrite->author_base = $city;

    $wp_rewrite->author_structure = '/%author%' . '/' . $wp_rewrite->author_base;

}
```

Comment: Your code is perfectly logic. But  there is a problem. If i am on the homepage and the url doesn't contain the username, all profile links on this page are still unchanged because there's nothing to parse.